# PHP Pulling a specific name from a dynamically created table

Tags: php, html

So I am at my wits end. Out of the more complex issues, this is the one that has just stumped me. I'm not sure if it's a HTML issue or a PHP issue, anymore. I've tried everything I could think up, and just nothing.
Ok so I need to pull a specific name out of a dynamically created table,  the Weapon’s Name to be exact. 
So User clicks the button “Delete weapon” and that weapon would be deleted. The query is fine; my issue is getting this name. If there was just one weapon and this wasn’t dynamic I would just go for the specific field name. That’s PHP 101. 
 This is the loop it's being pulled from:

```
while ( $weapons = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
            echo '
              <table width="780" border="1">
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">weapon</td>
                    <td>AttackBonus</td>
                    <td>crit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">

                        <input type="text" name="weaponName'.$i.'" id="weaponName'.$i.'"  size="10" value="'.$weapons["weaponsName"].'" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="weaponName" value="'.$weapons["weaponsName"].'"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="attackBonus'.$i.'" id="attackBonus'.$i.'"  size="10" value='.$weapons["weaponsAttackBonus"].' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="crit'.$i.'" id="crit'.$i.'"  size="10" value='.$weapons["weaponsCritical"].' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>type</td>
                    <td>range</td>
                    <td>ammunition</td>
                    <td>damage</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="type'.$i.'" id="type'.$i.'"  size="10" value='.$weapons["weaponsType"].' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="range'.$i.'" id="range'.$i.'"  size="10" value='.$weapons["weaponsRange"].' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="ammunition'.$i.'" id="ammunition'.$i.'"  size="10" value='.$weapons["weaponsAmmunition"].' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="damage'.$i.'" id="damage'.$i.'"  size="10" value='.$weapons["weaponsDamaage"].' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">
                        <input type="submit" formaction="include/deleteweapon.php"  formmethod="post" value="Delete Weapon"/>
                    </td>               
                </tr>
                </table>

    ';
        $i++;}
```

It’s probably something small, that’s how it’s always been my issue. I’ve tried a few different while loops. I’ve tried if statements with issets($_post[“weaponName0”], etc. I just don’t know.

Edit:
So I'm not very good with explaining what I need. The loop to display the information is fine, and yes the button needs to be there.

(I don't have enough rep to up load an image so here is the link)
http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8391/8468562067_0cd4158e35_b.jpg

This is what it looks like. I can not get the value of the weapon name. The output is fine here, it's when I need to delete that specific weapon, that I'm having issue with. I need that name. This is why I'm not sure if it's the HTML or the PHP. The button has to be iterated or whats the point? The mySQL is fine, that was the easy part.

I have an idea of what I can do, but in my opinion it's bad design and I think I would just have the same problem. I could add a check box for these fields to delete, and it'll be deleted after you try to save the character.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I don't get it, it looks like you have a "delete weapon" button for each iteration of the loop, meaning one delete button for each weapon, correct?

Comment: You are missing $i in name =weaponName , see how id got a got suffix value

Comment: thanks @h2ooooooo I'll try that out, and when I'm not frustrated I'll convert my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem, I believe in your HTML, you should do something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="weaponName[<?php print $i; ?>]" value="The Name" />
```

In your PHP, you should be able to access the name given an index:

```
$index = 1; // Some arbitrary index
$weapon_name = $_POST['weaponName'][$index];
```

Alternatively, and what I would do: In your form's action, specify an id:

```
<form action="delete.php?id=<?php print $weaponId; ?>" action="post">
```

Then in your PHP, you can do:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // This is the weapon ID
```

Then you can just pull the name directly from the database, using the ID.

Comment: I'll try it, tomorrow. It's been a frustrating day.

Comment: Thank you, the Get was what I needed, and as usual it's always something small. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a single delete button for each iteration of the loop. You should be able to set the name for deletion just as you set it as a label.

```
<input type=hidden name=weaponsName value=".$weapons['weaponsName'].">
<input type=submit ...>

$weaponsName = $_POST['weaponsName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_assoc, so you should use the field index, like this:

```
 $weapons["weaponsName"] // This is wrong


 $weapons[0] // This is the right approach
```

PS: You should not use the mysql extension....go for the mysqli or PDO ;)

Saludos.

Comment: The fetch isn't the problem, that is working correctly. The Fetch Assoc is at the top of the page.

Comment: Then what is the point of using this line:                          while ( $weapons = mysql_fetch_array($data)) . In this line you populate $weapons whit a fetch_array??? . Sorry but i don't understand that line....may be you shou do a var_dump on weapons after that line and before that line. Saludos :)

Comment: It's for the loop (not the values within the loop), for how many weapons a user has it iterates them.

Comment: But you should see the values on the $weapons array using var_dump or print_r ....may be there is a mix of values between using the same array on the fetch_assoc and fetch_array.....check that plssss xD......saludos ;)